# What is wrong with my rot-13 (Caesar Decipher) Javascript algorithm?

Tags: javascript

```js
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!
  

 
  
  var array=str.split(" ");
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){

    array[i]=array[i].split('');
  }
  
  
  for(var j=0;j<array.length;j++){
    for(var k=0;k<array[j].length;k++){
      var s=array[k];
      if(s=="!"||s=="?"||s=="."){
        s=s;
       }
      else if(s.charCodeAt(0)==77||s.charCodeAt(0)<77){
        s=String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0)+13);
      }
      else if(s.charCodeAt(0)>77){
        s=String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0)-13);
      }
    }
  
  
  for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    array[i]=array[i].join("");
  }
  array=array.join(" ");
 
   return array;
  
}
}

// Change the inputs below to test
rot13("IM JOE!");
```

So for example, rot13("SERR YBIR!") should give you "FREE LOVE!".
The error message says "TypeError:s.charCodeAt is not a function".

What's mean? How should I fix it?

Comment: perhaps you want `var s=array[j][k];`

Comment: What's the value of `s` when you try to do `charCodeAt()`?

Comment: Jaromanda I did that. And now, the function return IM JOE! no change

Comment: you have misplaced `}` ... if you indent your code PROPERLY, you'd see that - you also change `s` ... but never the array contents

Comment: you may also want to investigate `<=` comparison

Comment: @user132522, use my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var s=arr[k];` to `var s=arr[j][k];`

Also, you have to put the result in the array before joining them.

```js
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!
  var arr=str.split(" ");
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    arr[i]=arr[i].split('');
  }
  
  for(var j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
    for(var k=0;k<arr[j].length;k++){
      var s=arr[j][k];
      if(s=="!"||s=="?"||s=="."){
        s=s;
       }
       else if(s.charCodeAt(0)<=77){
        s=String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0)+13);
      } 
      else if(s.charCodeAt(0)>77){
        s=String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0)-13);
      }
      arr[j][k] = s;
    }
 }
 
  
  for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    arr[i]=arr[i].join("");
  }
  arr=arr.join(" ");
 
   return arr;
  
}

// Change the inputs below to test
alert(rot13("IM JOE!"));
```

Comment: @JaromandaX. There was no error. But, the logic was wrong. I fixed it.

Comment: By error, I meant error in logic (two of them, right)

Comment: I like this the best. Because theres basically just one change. array[j][k]=s. And the rest is my own work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the characters to process using `array[j][k]`

you also need to change the array, changing `s` does nothing

you have misplaced `}`

and you should look into `<=`

```
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!
    var array = str.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i].split('');
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < array[j].length; k++) {
            var s = array[j][k].charCodeAt(0);
            if (s >= 65 && s <= 77) {
                array[j][k] = String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0) + 13);
            } else if (s >= 78 && s <= 90) {
                array[j][k] = String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0) - 13);
            }
        }
    // this } was below the return statement, so only the first word would've been transformed
    }
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i].join("");
    }
    array = array.join(" ");
    return array;
}
// Change the inputs below to test
console.log(rot13("IM JOE!"));
console.log(rot13("LBH QVQ VG!"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the improvement. Made it much more conscise.

Answer (score 1):

Check your logic.
The position of return statement and array access are wrong.

```
function rot13(str) { 
  var array=str.split(" ");  
  for(var j=0;j<array.length;j++){  
    array[j]=array[j].split('');
    for(var k=0;k<array[j].length;k++){
      var s=array[j][k];
      if(s=="!"||s=="?"||s=="."){
        s=s;
      }
      else if(s.charCodeAt(0)==77||s.charCodeAt(0)<77){
        s=String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0)+13);
      }
      else if(s.charCodeAt(0)>77){
        s=String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0)-13);
      }
      array[j][k]=s;
    }
    array[j]=array[j].join("");
  }
  array=array.join(" ");
  return array;
}
// Change the inputs below to test
alert(rot13("SERR YBIR!"));
```